# Quick way to detect if a DataContext table or view exists

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Currently, I'm developing an application that depends on (and thus connects to) various databases via LINQ-to-SQL. For one of the databases, the connection string may vary and is thus configurable - however, the schema of this database is identical for all connection strings.

Because of the configurable connection string, I want to validate the DataContext during the startup of my application, to make sure that all tables and views my application uses, are available.

The `Table<T>` objects in the `DataContext` object are always initialized - even if the corresponding SQL table or view doesn't have any records.

So then. Currently, the validation check is performed as follows:

```
        bool valid = _dataContext.Articles.Count() > 0
            && _dataContext.Customers.Count() > 0
            && _dataContext.Orders.Count() > 0;
```

While this does work, the determination of the value of valid takes quite some time (every record of each Table is touched), which ultimately results in a time out. So, is there a faster, more reliable way to determine whether or not a `Table<T>` of a certain `DataContext` really exists as a table in the corresponding database?

Comment: A small improvement: use the Any() extension method instead of Count() > 0. Not an answer to the real question, though.

Comment: @Jørn - you should post that as an answer, as I think that is the best option here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an (untested) idea:

Grab the name of your table. You can hard code it in, or you can grab it programmatically via

```
TableAttribute attribute = (TableAttribute)typeof(MyTableObject)
                           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true)
                           .Single();
string name = attribute.Name;
```

`MyTableObject` is the LINQ-to-SQL generated object contained in your `Table`, i.e., the generic parameter `T` in `Table<T>`.

([`TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) is in [`System.Data.Linq.Mapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx).)

Use the [`DataContext.ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) method as in

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
var results = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'");
bool hasTable = results.Any(s => "dbo." + s == name);
```

Comment: Great, this is it. I removed the WHERE-clause and stored the results in a List<String> - 'var results' could only be enumerated once. Still, blazingly fast. Great.

Answer (score 4):

A slight change on Jason's answer (I gave him an upvote :))

```
public bool TableExistsInDatabase<T>()
{
  TableAttribute attribute = (TableAttribute)typeof(T)
                             .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true)
                             .Single();

  var result = ExecuteQuery<bool>(
                String.Format(
                  "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                   SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE 
                   SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT)", attribute.Name));

  return result.First();
}
```